# How to apply custom filters for John The Ripper when cracking RAR3 archive password?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking, hashcat, john-the-ripper

My problem is that I'm trying to crack RAR file with is encrypted with RAR3 encryption.
Decided to try with John The Ripper.
Here are clues I have from my friend.

1. Max password length is 8
2. Only capital letters or digits

And I need now filter to make John crack the password without trying to check small lowercase letters.
On hashcat it's easy to do but program do not support $RAR3$*1 type of hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to be running John 1.9.0 to support masks.  The following John mask specification:

```
john -1='?u?d' --mask='?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1'
```

Will match 8 characters of Upper and Digits.

The MASK documentation file from the distribution is available [here](https://fossies.org/linux/privat/john-1.9.0-jumbo-1.tar.xz/john-1.9.0-jumbo-1/doc/MASK?m=t) and goes into more detail about what you can do with masks.